# How to update DBD::ODBC from 1.56 to 1.59 (or later) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, sqitch

I'm new to sqitch. I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline to deploy snowflake using sqitch. So, I got sqitch and snowsql installed to my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Azure.

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
sqitch verify --target dev
```

and I get error regarding ODBC driver:

```
DBD::ODBC 1.59 required to manage Snowflake
```

Looks like [here is the package](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/libdbd-odbc-perl_1.56-1build1_arm64.deb.html) I have and it is the latest for my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

But I need [this one](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.10/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libdbd-odbc-perl_1.61-1_amd64.deb.html).

But if I got it right I need ti upgrade my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.10. Is it correct?
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to install unixODBC:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

That helped to successfully run the command:

```
sudo cpanm DBD::ODBC
```

Successfully installed DBD-ODBC-1.61